# Trying to Extract State Abbreviations

Tags: r

I have a list of addresses in a dataframe and I want to extract the state abbreviations into a new column.

I tried some code I saw on another question:

```
df$State <- str_extract(df$Address, "\\b[A-Z]{2}"))
```

It worked well for the most part but it also returned things like "NW" which was part of the address. I also tried:

```
ex_city_state(df$Address)
```

from the qdapRegex package which seemed to work but I'm not sure how to get the results into a new column. 
Here is an example of the addresses:

```
"212 E Superior St, Alma, MI 48801, USA"
"121 Industrial Rd, Belmont, CA 94002, USA"
"24 Gouverneur Ln, New York, NY 10005, USA"
"1701 Wright St, Madison, WI 53704, USA"
"15898 TX-123, San Marcos, TX 78666, USA"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could phrase this by looking for a two letter abbreviation which is immediately followed by a 5 digit ZIP code, e.g.

```
addresses <- c("212 E Superior St, Alma, MI 48801, USA",
               "121 Industrial Rd, Belmont, CA 94002, USA",
               "24 Gouverneur Ln, New York, NY 10005, USA",
               "1701 Wright St, Madison, WI 53704, USA",
               "15898 TX-123, San Marcos, TX 78666, USA")
states <- sub(".*\\b([A-Z]{2}) \\d{5}.*", "\\1", addresses)
states

   1    2    3    4    5 
"MI" "CA" "NY" "WI" "TX"
```

Answer (score 3):

`ex_city_state` returns you a list of vectors. To add it to a new column you could `unlist` them.

```
df$city_state <- unlist(qdapRegex::ex_city_state(df$Address))
```

---

Or there is a inbuilt character vector in R `state.abb` which has got abbreviations for all the states. You could create a pattern using that and extract the states

```
stringr::str_extract(df$Address, paste0(state.abb, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "MI" "CA" "NY" "WI" "TX"
```

which can be done in base R using `sub`

```
sub(paste0(".*(", paste0(state.abb, collapse = "|"), ").*"), "\\1", df$Address)
```